# Exporting large data in Excel Sheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel

I have UI where user can select more than 2000 rows and after clicking on the export button , all the values selected will be exported to excel.
But when i try to export more than 1000 data the Page gets frozen and it doesnot export.
Below is code:-

```
function get(){
var table = document.getElementById('table_0');
var numRows = table.rows.length;
var category = "";
var rows = "<tr><td>Date</td><td>Number</td><td>Title</td></tr>";

for(var i=0;i<numRows;i++){
    var values = [];
    var cells1 = table.rows[i].cells;
    var checkBoxes = cells1[0].getElementsByTagName('input');

    for(var counter=1; counter<checkBoxes.length; counter++){
        if(checkBoxes[counter].type =='checkbox' && checkBoxes[counter].checked == true){
            for(var ic=1,it=(cells1.length-1);ic<it;ic++){                                      
                if(cells1[0].innerHTML != null){
                    divs=cells1[ic].textContent;
                    values.push(divs);                      
                }               
            }
            rows = rows + "<tr><td>" + values[0].trim() + "</td><td>" + values[1].trim() + "</td><td>" + values[2].trim() + "</td></tr>";

        }           
    }
    console.log(rows);
    console.log("done");
    $("#resultTable").html(rows);
   }
```

Below is the code to Export and download the excel in IE.

```
function ExportToCsv(tableName, name) {

get();

var tab_text = '<html xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">';
tab_text = tab_text + '<head><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet>';
tab_text = tab_text + '<x:Name>Test Sheet</x:Name>';
tab_text = tab_text + '<x:WorksheetOptions><x:Panes></x:Panes></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet>';
tab_text = tab_text + '</x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml></head><body>';
tab_text = tab_text + "<table border='1px'>";
var exportTable = $('#' + tableName).clone();
exportTable.find('input').each(function (index, elem) { $(elem).remove(); });


    $("#myDiv").hide();
tab_text = tab_text + exportTable.html();
tab_text = tab_text + '</table></body></html>';
var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
//var data_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8';
var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

var fileName = name + '_' + parseInt(Math.random() * 10000000000) + '.xls';
if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) {
    if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
        var blob = new Blob([tab_text], {
            type: "application/csv;charset=utf-8;"
            //type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8;"
        });
        navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
    }
} else {
    $('#Approve').attr('href', data_type + ', ' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));
    $('#Approve').attr('download', fileName);
}
```

}

Why this code not exporting large data more than 1000?
Any help?

Comment: Any sense of at what point it is quitting?  Any console errors of note?

Comment: No error it doesnt quit it will be frozen untill i close the browser and restart.

Comment: Huh, well that definitely sounds like an infinite loop-- but as to why the arbitrary limit of 1000 it's difficult to say.  On occasion, I've been able to hit the pause button in the dev tools when I was caught in some infinite loop in this manner and been able to take a look at the stack trace walk around a bit to try to get my bearings and see if I could figure out where the problem was occurring. You could also try adding a conditional breakpoint somewhere for when your loop count is close to 1000 and try to see if you can step until you see what is wrong...Not a solution, but maybe helpful.

Comment: Not a "proper" solution, but loop the export in 500 line chunks and see if that completes with no errors. Depends on your focus - getting the job done or making a one-hit code...

Comment: Is it possible in same worksheet to add 500 lines ? or need to go for another worksheet after 500 rows exported?